# Copying a specific column from one text file to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a bunch of .txt files from which i want to copy a specific column (from all of them) into one .txt file. The output.txt file needs to be created

For e.g.

```
file1.txt
a b c
j k l

file2.txt
d e f
m n o

file3.txt
g h i
p q r

output.txt
b e h
k n q
```

For the same I am looking for a batch file in windows that can help me achieve this. Any kind of help would be really appreciated :). I am a mere rookie in batch scripting and hence pardon me if this sounds a very basic problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but I had a similar although not exact problem when working with strings in batch files. I became so frustrated I ended up learning and using python.

In Python, this would be as simple as:

```
for i in range(1,4): 
    f='c:\\file'+str(i)+'.txt' # Creates a variable for file1.txt, file2.txt formatted  as c:\file1.txt. Path can be changed as needed. 
    f = open(f) # Opens the file 
    string=f.read() # Adds the contents of the file to a string
    print(string.split('\t')[1]+'\t'+string.split('\t')[4]) # splits the string by tabs, and returns the 2nd and 5th item.
```

This prints it out to the screen, writing it out to a file is trivial from here.

Comment: Thanks @multiphrenic. Just to clarify: the column values in my txt files are floating point numbers and all the columns are tab delimited!

Comment: Code above should work then, if you're willing to use python. To write it to a file would be as simple as adding:

`out = open('C:\\output.txt','w')`
change `print(...` to `file.write(...`
and finish with `file.close()`

the nice thing with this is that it's readable and easy to change as your requirements change..

Comment: Sure, I would wait to see if anyone can up with a solution using a batch scripting. If not, I will bug you again :). Thanks a lot, now I know I have a back up plan ;)!

Comment: Do you know whats the cause of indentation error in line 2 of the code. I changed the path to location where the file1.txt and file2.txt are, but still it doesnt proceed further.

Comment: python uses indents to determine code blocks. ive changed the code above, there was an extra indent, it should work now

Answer (score 1):

This batch solution will take the 2nd char from all the lines from each file in the folder and output them to `output.txt`, wow that's a mouthful! :)

```
for %%a in (file*.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in (%%a) do echo %%b >>output.txt
)
```

Getting them to line up will be more difficult, is that strictly necessary, or can they be in a list, one char per line?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my problem is a little different. I want the '2 char from all the lines in each of the files' to be placed in different columns in output file. Hope this it not a mouthful :)

Comment: Sorry, just realized you want all the lines, I have fixed my answer. The columns output is a little more tricky, atm my answer will put them in a list, I take it you really need them to be in columns? Haha not so much :)

Comment: yeah, to give you an overview I am going to use this txt file in a OCTAVE script which is coded for a format as I mentioned. with your batch script I would need to change this OCTAVE script, which I dont want to as its a little complicated. Hope you can make it to different columns :)

Comment: Ok, no worries, leave it with me and I will see if I can come up with something!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your consideration :)

Comment: Sorry, I have been trying to think of an easy way to do it but I can't :( I'm sure it will be possible in batch but it's most likely very painful to write! If @mutliphrenic's answer works, go with theirs :)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: different way** of doing that (probably more straightforward), this one has another limit - size of available variable/env. space (at about ~32kB for XP, not limited Vista upwards - at least per MS docs). It creates a *kind of* array variables to hold your transposed lines and then outputs them:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "tab=   "

for %%F in (file*.txt) do (
  set /a count=0
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=%tab%" %%L in (%%F) do (
    set /a count+=1
    for /L %%T in (!count!,1,!count!) do (
       set L[!count!]=!L[%%T]!%%L%tab%
    )
  )
)
for /L %%L in (1,1,%count%) do echo !L[%%L]!
```

First, let me say that `batch` is not best suited for this task (which would've been trivial, say in `C`), but if you have to use it, here is a way:

```
    @echo off
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "tab=   "

    for /f %%C in ('dir /b file*.txt') do set /a count+=1

    (for %%F in (file*.txt) do (
      set line=0
      for /f "tokens=2 delims=%tab%" %%V in (%%F) do (
        set "outline=%%F"
        for /l %%N in (1,1,!line!) do (set "outline=%tab%!outline!")
        set outline=!outline!%tab%%%V
        set /a line+=1
        echo !outline!
      )

    )) >presorted.txt

    set /a cutoff=%count%-1

    set line=0
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=%tab%" %%O in ('sort /r presorted.txt') do (
      set outp=%%O%tab%!outp!
      set /a lc=!line!^%%count%
      if !lc!==%cutoff% (
        echo !outp!
        set  "outp="
      )
      set /a line+=1
    )
```

How it works:

- Fist, check how many files will be processed. This gives a count of columns. (First `for` and `count` variable)
- Read each input file, output requested column  modified so it will be preceded by number of tabs equal to line number and file name to intermediary file. (Second block delimited by `()`)
- Sort this file so consecutive lines correspond to consecutive columns in  final output (`sort /r presorted.txt`)
- Transpose blocks of lines into columns using `modulo count` to start new line (last `for` block)

Notes:

- order of columns is depended on sort order of file names.
- all files have to have the same number of lines
- `"tab=   "` (in 3rd line) must contain actual tab
- it assumes ascii-ish encoding (where `tab` sorts before any printable character).
- it assumes no `!` characters in input (they need special handling when delayed expansion is on`)
- output is to the screen. If file output is required, put the code into a batch file and then run `mybatchfile.bat >output.txt`

Comment: I followed your instructions( though I don't completely understand the 2nd and 3rd bullet of 'How it Works'). But I get a txt file which contain the 'file names' of the these individual txt files and are in different line than different columns. Its jumbled up with tabs at some lines in beginning.

Comment: I got this script from another posting, but this works fine only if the files has 2 lines. My files are big (48002 lines to be exact). Any idea on how to modify it?: http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/copying-a-specific-column-from-one-text-file-to-another/28745.html

Comment: @NeelabhGupta This code outputs to screen. What you see in a txt file (`presorted.txt`) is just an intermediate/temp file. I've put addtional note how to output it to file. It will run for more than two lines, but sadly, not for 48000 :( - batch file line length at ~8k chars is the limit. Your file names (you mentioned at computing.net) will also give you problems as numbering is not padded with `0`s, that means they will sort different than you'd expect them. Is batch really your only possibility? Even sticking to native Win tools, vbscript or powershell would be easier and more effective.

Comment: okay, then I think batch is not the way to go about it. The batch is not a strict possibility but might be I was more comfortable using it ;). I was trying to use the python code as posted above but it gives me an indentation error for 2nd line. How do you propose a solution using vbscript or powershell?

Comment: @NeelabhGupta Added another way - please check if this works for you. It also outputs to screen, you'd have to  run mybatchfile.bat >output.txt to output to file.

Comment: This work perfectly, but it has a limit on size of the txt file? It doesnot work for number of lines I have (although is good enough for lines upto 500..from what I tested).

Comment: @NeelabhGupta Depends on OS. Under XP/2003 there is a limit on total size of variables (32k), Vista up it shouldn't matter

Comment: i tried on XP, might be that was a problem. I will check again on windows 7..but my each txt files are around 60 MB..will it be fine?